# Cambiar unidades eje y de un histograma con matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

¿es posible cambiar las unidades del eje y de un histograma creado con matplotlib (plt.hist), y que en vez de counts represente un porcentaje (counts/total)?

El código sería algo así:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

# Tengo varias listas con diferente cantidad de valores
lista1 = [2,9,8,6,3,4,5,6,2,3,4,5,7,9,1]
lista2 = [2,4,5,1,9,8,9,1,2,2,0,3,5,2,3,7,6,8,9,2,3,4,1,2,3]

bins = np.linspace(0, 10, 5)
plt.hist(lista1, bins, alpha=0.5, label = 'lista1')
plt.hist(lista2, bins, alpha=0.5, label = 'lista2')
```

Muchas gracias.

Comment: Se puede pero haría falta que mostraras tu código ([mcve]) para poder basar las respuestas en algo concreto y en base a las bibliotecas que uses para menejar los datos (NumPy, Pandas, etc). Saludos.

Comment: ¿Muestras los dos histogramas en la misma gráfica superpuestos o serian dos gráficas distintas?

Comment: En la misma gráfica superpuestos

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si solo mostraras un histograma por gráfica lo podrias hacer solo modificando las marcas (ticks) del eje ***y***. Al mostrar dos necesitas calcular la frecuencia relativa de cada elemento de cada una de las listas. Lo más simple es usar el argumento [`weights`](http://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist) de `matplotlib.pyplot.hist` de forma que el peso de cada elemento sea `1/len(lista)`.

Para crear el array de pesos eficientemente te puedes valer de NumPy:

```
np.ones_like(lista1) / len(lista1)
```

Con esto obtenemos la frecuencia relativa de los elementos en el eje ***y***, para que lo muestre en tanto por ciento basta con formatear las marcas del eje ***y*** adecuadamente.

El código quedaría algo así:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

lista1 = [2,9,8,6,3,4,5,6,2,3,4,5,7,9,1]
lista2 = [2,4,5,1,9,8,9,1,2,2,0,3,5,2,3,7,6,8,9,2,3,4,1,2,3]
bins = np.linspace(0, 10, 5)

plt.hist(lista1, bins, weights=np.ones_like(lista1) / len(lista1),
         alpha=0.5, label = 'lista1', histtype='bar', ec='black')
plt.hist(lista2, bins, weights=np.ones_like(lista2) / len(lista2),
         alpha=0.5, label = 'lista2', histtype='bar', ec='black')

formatter = FuncFormatter(lambda y, _: str(y * 100) + '%')
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
plt.show()
```

Y la salida (Matplotlib 2.0.2 ) es esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Edición**: La función `lambda` lo único que hace es retornar por cada valor de ***y*** ese mismo valor multiplicado por 100 y agregando el símbolo `%`. De esta forma formateamos el eje ***y*** para que muestre la frecuencia relativa en tanto por ciento.

> Aviso: si se usa LaTeX hay que escapar el `%` por lo que la función lambda debería ser:
>   `lambda y, _: str(y * 100) + r'$\%$`

**Edición:**

Si quieres mostrar ambos histogramas separados:

- Ambos en la misma ventana pero diferentes gráficas (una instancia de **plt.figure**):

  ```
  import numpy as np
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

  lista1 = [2,9,8,6,3,4,5,6,2,3,4,5,7,9,1]
  lista2 = [2,4,5,1,9,8,9,1,2,2,0,3,5,2,3,7,6,8,9,2,3,4,1,2,3]
  bins = np.linspace(0, 10, 5)

  fig = plt.figure()
  ax1 = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 1)
  ax2 = fig.add_subplot(2, 1, 2)

  ax1.hist(lista1, bins, alpha=0.5, label = 'lista1')
  ax2.hist(lista2, bins, alpha=0.5, label = 'lista2')

  formatter = FuncFormatter(lambda y, _: '{:3.2f}%'.format(y/len(lista1)*100))
  ax1.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

  formatter = FuncFormatter(lambda y, _: '{:3.2f}%'.format(y/len(lista2)*100))
  ax2.yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

  plt.show()
  ```
- Gráficos separados cada uno en su propia ventana (dos instancias de `plt.figure()`)

  ```
  import numpy as np
  import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

  lista1 = [2,9,8,6,3,4,5,6,2,3,4,5,7,9,1]
  lista2 = [2,4,5,1,9,8,9,1,2,2,0,3,5,2,3,7,6,8,9,2,3,4,1,2,3]
  bins = np.linspace(0, 10, 5)

  fig1 = plt.figure()
  plt.hist(lista1, bins, alpha=0.5, label = 'lista1')
  formatter = FuncFormatter(lambda y, _: '{:3.2f}%'.format(y/len(lista1)*100))
  plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)


  fig2 = plt.figure()
  plt.hist(lista2, bins, alpha=0.5, label = 'lista2')
  formatter = FuncFormatter(lambda y, _: '{:3.2f}%'.format(y/len(lista2)*100))
  plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

  plt.show()
  ```

Comment: Si sólo quisiera mostrar un histograma por gráfica, ¿como sería? ¿Añadiría `formatter = FuncFormatter(lambda y, _: str(y * 100) + '%')` y `plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)` debajo de cada `plt.hist`?

Comment: @Rg111 si, esa es la idea más o menos. He editado la respuesta, mira al final de ella. Te dejo dos opciones mostrando los histogramas separados, una separados pero en la misma ventana y otra separados cada uno en su ventana. Saludos.