# Cambiar valor que muestran los ejes

Tags: python, matplotlib, axis

Tengo una imagen en python que grafico con el siguiente código:

```
from PIL import Image
plt.figure()
im = Image.open('background.png')  
extent = Deg2meters([11.0,12.5],[54,54.75], ref).T
extent = np.delete(extent, np.s_[2], axis=1)
extentlist=[extent[0,0],extent[1,0],extent[0,1],extent[1,1]]
pylab.imshow(im, extent = extentlist, aspect=1.16)
```

La función `Deg2meters` lo único que hace es convertir grados (longitud y latitud) en metros a partir de una cierta referencia (necesito esto, porque después encima grafico datos que están en metros). Esto hace que en mis ejes aparezcan los valores en metros, pero lo que quiero es que aprezcan en grados nuevamente. No puedo cambiar los valores que ploteo a grados, necesito plotear en metros, pero que los ejes muestren grados, manteniendo claro la proporción.

La siguiente imagen muestra lo que tengo a la izquierda y lo que quiero a la derecha:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He intento con `plt.xticks` sin llegar nada.

PD: tengo una función que convierte los metros en grados, eso no es problema.

Comment: Juanca es posible hacerlo, la idea es similar a la que muestro en https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/83248/15089 solo que también quieres cambiar los sticks (`ax.set_xticks()` y `ax.set_yticks()`) y no solo el label que muestran. Sería de gran ayuda para darte una respuesta basada en tu problema que aportaras si es posible todos los datos para simular la gráfica (imágen, `Deg2meters` y `ref`). Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dado que para reproducir tu gráfica hacen falta datos de los que no disponemos voy a darte un ejemplo que creo que es similar a lo que quieres y que deberias poder adaptar sin problemas.

Imaginemos que tenemos ciertos datos que representan temperatura en grados Celsius:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([10, 15, 20, 26, 30, 32, 35, 35.5, 35, 30, 28, 20, 12, 10])
plt.show()
```

Lo cual nos muestra una gráfica simple donde el eje y representa los grados en escala Celsius:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Imaginemos que queremos que la escala del eje ***y*** sea en grados Fahrenheit pero sin modificar los datos originales (que están en escala Celsius) y con la posibilidad de agregar nuevos gráficos cuyos datos están en Celsius sin pasarlos primero a fahrenheit. Además, queremos que el eje ***y*** muestre solo las marcas correspondientes a 53, 71 y 90 grados fahrenheit.

Para ello nos valemos primero de `ax.set_yticks` para especificar las marcas que queremos. Hay que recordar que el gráfico está en todo momento en escala Celsius por lo que a `ax.set_yticks` hay que pasarle las marcas en esa escala. Para ello podemos ayudarnos de una función que pase de fahrenheits a celsius o hacerlo manualmente.

Hecho esto solo queda formatear el eje para que muestre las etiquetas en grados Fahrenheits en todo momento, aunque el gráfico mantiene la proporción y sigue trabajano en escala Celsius. Para ello nos valemos de `matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter` y de una función que pase grados celsius a fahrenheit.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

def celsius_a_fahrenheit(c, *args):
    return c * (9 / 5) + 32

def fahrenheit_a_celsius(f):
    return (f - 32) / (9 / 5)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot([10, 15, 20, 26, 30, 32, 35, 35.5, 35, 30, 28, 20, 12, 10])

# Asignamos las marcas que queramos para el eje y (53, 71 y 90 grados fahrenheits)
yticks = [fahrenheit_a_celsius(s) for s in (53, 71, 90)]
ax.set_yticks(yticks)

# Formateamos el eje para que la escala mostrada sea grados fahrenheits.
formatter = FuncFormatter(celsius_a_fahrenheit)
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)

# Podemos añadir nuevos datos en escala celsius sin convertirlos a fahrenheits.
ax.plot([2, 13, 21, 28, 17, 12 ,0])

plt.show()
```

Con lo que obtenemos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Observa como después de formatear el eje creamos un nuevo gráfico con datos en Celsius. A pesar de mostrar la escala del eje ***y*** en fahrenheit, la escala que usa para graficar es celsius por lo que no hay que convertir los nuevos datos a faherenheit.

Como se puede observar abajo a la izquierda al pasar el puntero por la gráfica muestra de forma automática los valores en escala fahrenheit.

Si queremos hacer algo similar con el eje ***x*** el proceso es el mismo.

> **Aviso**: código probado y válido para Python 2.7.13 y 3.6.1 con Matplotlib 2.0.2.

Comment: Muchas gracias, lo he conseguido, he tenido que cambiar algunas cosillas del codigo original, pero bien, he conseguido hacerlo. Ahora el unico problema es que no funciona bien el hecho de usar `plt.xlim` y `plt.ylim` es como si no hiciese caso.

Comment: Edit: todo solucionado, era problema mio, pero no me deja editar el comentario anterior. Gracias de nuevo.